# How to set multiple values to one declared parameter in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server Management Studio, I want to set multiple values to one declared parameter. I wonder if the script below would work:

```
declare @Parameter_A     NVARCHAR(MAX)
set @Parameter_A = 'ABC, DEF, GHI, JKL'
```

If the above script is not the correct way to achieve what I want, could someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do with @Parameter_A. You may alternatively consider table variables to store multiple values.

Comment: In fact, I am doing a StoredProc. The complete StoredProc will be deployed and retrieved to a report layout (SSRS). Before deployment, I would like to do query testing to ensure my StoredProc can generate the correct result.

Comment: You could then follow my suggestion in the answer to define a table variable in the format your report will expect, then output the result of the table variable with relevant sample data to do your testing.

Comment: Thanks @JasonW . This might be the easiest way for me to do query testing.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment, it completely depends on what you plan to do with the parameter as to the best method to accomplish this (and perhaps to add even how you get the selected values to be stored). If you can elaborate on those 2 things, we can probably give you better suggestions.

One thing you can easily use to store multiple values without having to get into parsing those values back out is to use table variables:

```
DECLARE @Params TABLE (A NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT @Params VALUES
    ('ABC'), ('DEF'), ('GHI'), ('JKL')
SELECT * FROM @Params
```

If you must iterate over the list, you can modify this to add an identity to simplify the logic.

```
DECLARE @Params TABLE (A NVARCHAR(MAX), Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1))
```

Now you can iterate with logic like this:

```
DECLARE @i INT = 0
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @Params P WHERE Id >= @i) BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM @Params P WHERE Id = @i
    SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

Or for scenarios where you only wish to process each unique value once, you can just use a `DELETE` (no need for additional identity attribute):

```
DECLARE @A NVARCHAR(MAX)
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @Params P) BEGIN
    SET @A = (SELECT TOP 1 A FROM FROM @Params P)
    -- Perform any work
    DELETE @Params WHERE A = @A 
END
```

Comment: Also, I suggest to have two columns in the table variable:
1. A NVARCHAR
2. Counter INT IDENTITY (1,1)

This will help you Iterate the table variable without much of a fuss. Else you may have to use a Cursor

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is going to help but... there is a type called cursor, it's like a vector or an array. It's used like this:

```
CURSOR name IS SELECT something
FROM some_table;
```

That way you can store a lot of information in a cursor called "name".
To iterate through its values, you can use a loop like this:

```
OPEN name;

LOOP

    FETCH name INTO x;
    EXIT WHEN name%NOTFOUND;

    dbms_output.put_line(x);

END LOOP;

CLOSE name;
```

This way you print all values stored. Hope that helped!